# windows 10 error code: 0xc000014c

Tags: windows-10, recovery

I updated my windows 10 laptop a few weeks ago and it went without a hitch.  When I rebooted the laptop last night, I got a blue screen titled "Recovery:  Your PC/Device needs to be repaired".  The error message is

```
  The Boot Configuration Data for your PC is missing or contains errors.
  File:\Boot\BCD
  Error Code: 0xc000014c
  You will need to use recovery tools.  If you don't have any installation media (like a disc or USB device), contact your PC administrator or PC/Device manufacturer.
```

What I have tried:

- interrupt power on three times to try to get into recovery/repair mode, but without success
- enter the SNID of my laptop into the manufacturer's website to try to download recovery media, but the website says that it's no longer available (the laptop came with window 7 and has since been updated to window 10)

Note:

- The laptop has crucial data/software license so I cannot just wipe the HD and reinstall the OS
- It seems (?) that the only way to obtain window recovery media is via a window machine?  But I have no access to another window machine
- I am a linux person and I am not at all familiar with window -- this comment is NOT meant to start a flame war, but simply to profess my ignorance and ask for help
- This laptop used to dual-boot windows 7 with ubuntu, but that was years ago, and the ubuntu partition was wiped out when it got updated to window 10.  I have had no blue screen issue at all until now

I'd be most appreciative for your help and guidance on how/where to download the appropriate recovery media, and the steps involved to carry this out.  THANKS SO MUCH!

Comment: No flame war brother, I hate ALL operating systems.  :)  `But I have no access to another window machine` .. think outside of the box.  MOST personal computers run windows.. SOMEONE might be able to help you create the windows installation media. :)  Again..I hate Windows, Mac, and Linux for different reasons.  Not trying to start a flame war!

Comment: Perhaps I *should have* said that I LOVE Windows, Mac, and Linux for different reasons.. that would have been WAY more positive. :)

Comment: I hate them all too, but each for a different reason. If only we had **one standard**… cue compulsory XKCD ref https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: If a system contains "crucial data/software license" you really should consider making a full backup from it so you can restore it in case of problems.

Comment: If this is mission-critical, where is your backup? All hard drives fail. If it were me, I would be seeking a bonded hard-drive recovery expert, not playing around.

Comment: This error is symptomatic of a disk going bad. Use a Linux Live CD/USB and save your crucial data. Reinstalling Windows 10 is not a problem, as it will auto-activate itself, but you might need to replace the disk (if it's worth it).

Comment: @ harryc:  Thanks!  I just did a SMART disk test and it came out okay.   @CMasMas:  I finally found another W10 box, made a recovery disk there and fixed my machine.    Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

Some free third-party tools on a USB drive can help fix the BCD issue:

- [AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard](https://www.diskpart.com/free-partition-manager.html), as [described by AOMEI.](https://www.diskpart.com/articles/windows-failed-to-start-file-boot-bcd-3889.html)
- [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) rescue media, as [described by Macrium.](http://reflect.macrium.com/help/v5/Rescue_CDs/Fix_Boot_Problems.htm)

These tools use Windows RE (AKA "WinPE") or other OS to boot from the flash drive.

Another choice is to download the [Windows 10 ISO from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and use their Media Creation Tool to create a USB device to reinstall Windows 10, *theoretically* keeping all your files and licenses. This is easiest done on a Windows PC; [doing so on Linux](https://itsfoss.com/bootable-windows-usb-linux/) is more involved.

**N.B.:** *Make a disk image before making any changes that could lose all your licenses and data.* Using Reflect Free, for example, use the same media shown above to make a full disk image.